# Redis data sync for Heroku

Tags: heroku, redis, dbmigrate

Is there a way I can sync my local redis store to the remote store in Heroku? What is possible is a migrating the local data to the heroku server and running the 'SET' command yourself via the heroku console. Is there a smarter way, like https://github.com/pedro/heroku-mongo-sync which was done for MongoDB?

Comment: Do replication and check db size before "slave of"

Answer (score 1):

If your local server is available to the web, you could set it up as a slave to the Heroku one:

http://redis.io/topics/replication